# Gstreamer with multiple audio sources goes out of sync

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I have two audio sources (wav files), convert and resample them separately and send them to different Alsa sinks in the same pipeline. Now, in my opinion Gstreamer should handle the Sync of all sources in a pipeline. Unfortunately, it does not. After some seeking and playing/pausing, the two sources go out of sync.

How can I make Gstreamer sync all sources in the same pipeline? I am working on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: They are different devices I assume?

Comment: I tried both. But it also desyncs with the same device.

Answer (score 0):

I routed all audiostreams through an audiomixer-plugin and used audioconverter's mix-matrix to map to the correct channel. Now it's working stable. I don't know, why it's necessary.